# Prevent remote database to be queried multiple times in PowerBI

Tags: sql, database, powerbi, powerquery, m

What is the best approach / design to query a remote data table in Power BI when multiple following queries depend on the queried data table to prevent the remote data table to queried multiple times?

---

**Details**

Let's say I have a remote data base server `my_db_server` with a database `my_db` which I query for a specific data table `my_source_data_table`. Afterwards I am using two other queries in PowerBI which depend on the initial query of the remote data table. I want to execute the query of the remote table only ONCE, and then use the cached data in an efficient way for the other two queries to prevent querying the remote database server multiple times.

---

**Step 1 - Access remote database**

Hence I add the following query in PowerBI to access the remote table

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("<my_db_server>"),
    Database = Source{[Name="<my_db>"]}[Data],
    MySourceDataTable = Database {[Schema="dbo",Item="<my_source_datatable>"]}[Data],
in
    MySourceDataTable
```

---

**Step 2 - Depending queries**

I now have two sub queries, which use this table as input and query for them, e.g.

Query A - Order columns by Foo,Bar

```
let
    Source = MySourceDataTable,
    ReorderColumnsFooBar = Table.ReorderColumns(Source ,{"Foo", "Bar"})
in
    ReorderColumnsFooBar
```

Query B - Order columns by Bar, Foo

```
let
    Source = MySourceDataTable,
    ReorderColumnsBarFoo = Table.ReorderColumns(Source ,{"Bar", "Foo"})
in
    ReorderColumnsBarFoo
```

---

How does PowerBI proceed in this case? Is it like:

1. Query remote database to resolve `MySourceDataTable`
2. Resolve `ReorderColumnsFooBar` using cached `MySourceDataTable`
3. Resolve `ReorderColumnsBarFoo` using cached `MySourceDataTable`

Does it use a cached version of 1) or are steps 2) and 3) each executing query 1) again?
Can I improve the situation using a `Table.Buffer(MySourceDataTable)` at the end of 1) to explicitly cache the table?

Testing these different approaches didn't seem to bring a boost in speed. Currently my whole query takes about 90sec and I would like to speed it up, since the remote query takes up 80% of the time.

Comment: The data is cached when you use [import mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand#import-mode).

Comment: If I understand correctly, _import mode_ is the default mode, hence I must be using this mode already? I cannot find any setting to actively change the mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Query streams data each time from the source. For instance, if you have two queries which both get data from a DB and the data changes in the split second between the execution of query 1 and query 2, you will get different data extracted.

Table.Buffer only caches within a single query so to answer your question, steps 2 & 3 both execute query 1 again.

You can read more background here: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2020/08/26/5417/how-power-query-thinks

If you want to improve your query time (90 seconds isn't long), you could take more advantage of query folding by reordering your steps. You could also optimise the M that is being run in each query - transformation choice and the order of operations can have a big impact on performance.

Comment: The video explains the behaviour very good. But I cannot imagine that this is the most efficient way. If I need to query the remote data table just once and can process the result in sub queries afterwards this must be more efficient than executing the remote query for each sub query? In my use case removing all but one remote query results in processing time of 13 secs vs. 90 secs with multiple sub queries. So I guess there must be room for improvement to like 20 secs in total with some sort of caching of the remote query result!?

Comment: So you are saying that Power BI - from your understanding - has no way to cache the result of a remotely queried table to be used in sub queries!? Hence I can never be sure to have the exacxt same data (might have changed between two queries) and no real efficient management of network resource due to multiple queries of actually the same data?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your input and answer David. However I would like to keep this question open for now in case someone else has a different idea / approach. I still think that this is an inefficient way to query a single data source for multiple destination tables and hope there is another way.

Comment: Fair enough but that is definitely how PQ works.